# How to handle master-detail with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

If role is an STI table:

```
class Role< ActiveRecord::Base
   self.inheritance_column= :role_type 
end
```

And Student & Counselor inherit Role:

```
class Student< Role
end

class Counselor< Role
end
```

And StudentDetail keeps extra information about one student:

```
class StudentDetail< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
end
```

And a user can be both student and counselor:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roles
    has_one :student
    has_one :counselor
end
```

And number is a column in StudentDetail,
And role_id is a column in StudentDetail

Is it possible to get the following syntax to work?

```
User.first.student.number
```

Meaning: "if Role table has one student with user_id == User.first.id then User.first.student is not null and if StudentDetail has role_id== Student.where("user_id= ?", User.first.id).first.id, make "student" act as a StudentDetail record and get the number field."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have the indirection `User.first.student.student_detail.number` out of the box. I don't think this hurts much :-)

I see two options (at least) how to go further:

- Define methods for the `StudentDetail` methods in `Student`:

  ```
  def number
    self.student_detail ? self.student_detail.number : nil
  end
  ```
- Use method missing to do that automatically:

  ```
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    self.student_detail ? self.student_detail.send(name, *args, &block) : nil
  end
  ```

Comment: well def number; self.try(:student_detail).try(:number); end
would be more succint.
I ended up doing "has_one student_detail through student"
but +1 for method_missing.